# footline of a beamer slide from RTL and with arabic language

Tags: beamer, header-footer, polyglossia, arabic

I am using **polyglossia** to write Arabic language presentation and I have a problem with the **footline** which doesn't accept the **Arabic** language. Although I have tried a lot of answers about the footline, I can't solve the problem, any help, please?

This is a sample code that produces the first slide:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\RTList}{\raggedleft\rightskip\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother

 % RTL triangle for itemize
 \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}  
 {\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\bullet
$}} 

% re-definition of the title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,sep=8pt,center]{title}
\inserttitle \par \insertsubtitle \par
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=8cm,center,wd=0.7\textwidth]{author}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}%
\centering
\insertauthor
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}%
\centering
\director
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\vfill
\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute \par
\vfill
\centering
\insertdate\par
\vfill
}

% to align the subsection in the toc to left
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[ball unnumbered]

\title[عنوان مختصر]{عنوان باللغة بالعربي}
\subtitle[عنوان مختصر]{
عنوان فرعي}
\author
{تقديم: \\ اسم القدم}
\newcommand{\director}{إشراف:\\ اسم المشرف}
\institute{اسم الجامعة}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**And this is the resulting slide:**

[image]

And I would like the footline to be like the picture below but in arabic and from right to left:
[image]

Comment: What would you use in RTL: `1/42` or `42/1` for the framenumber?

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to write 42/1

Comment: Good to know! I changed the order of the frame number, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Times New Roman}

\title[عنوان مختصر]{عنوان باللغة بالعربي}
\subtitle[عنوان مختصر]{عنوان فرعي}
\author{تقديم: \\ اسم القدم}
\institute{اسم الجامعة}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \textenglish{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \hspace*{2ex}\inserttotalframenumber{} / \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{2em}\textarabic{\insertshortdate}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\textarabic{\insertshorttitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%    
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
        (\textarabic{\insertshortinstitute})~~\textarabic{\insertshortauthor}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the second time you help me thank you a lot but is there any way to make the date appear as the date in my first picture?

Comment: @AliMhrez You're welcome! Try with `\textarabic{\insertshortdate}`

Comment: Of course, you will solve it I can't thank you enough.